Unsure about reduced state of entangled bits after measurement in different basis
I am following some notes that show how, for system $(A, B) = \frac{2}{\sqrt5}|00\rangle_{AB} + \frac{1}{\sqrt5}|11\rangle_{AB}$, the density matrix elements (in standard basis) for the reduced state of qubit $B$ is independent of the basis used in measuring $A$
It is clear why if $A$ is measured to be $|0\rangle$, then $B$ must be $|0\rangle$ as well: because there is 0 probability of a state $|01\rangle_{AB}$. But the notes state that when measuring $A$ in the Hadamard basis $\{ |+\rangle, |-\rangle \}$, then if $A$ is $|+\rangle$, then $B$ must be $\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}|0\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}|1\rangle$.
I am unsure how this state of $B$ has been arrived at. Doing $|+\rangle \otimes B$ doesn't give back the original $(A, B)$ state, would I have to convert the original $(A, B)$ into Hadamard basis before performing the measurement on $A$?

If you are measuring qubit $A$ in the $|\pm\rangle$ basis and get the answer $+$, then the state after measurement is computed by
$$
(|+\rangle\langle +|\otimes I)(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}|00\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}|11\rangle)
$$
(up to normalisation). This is just
$$
|+\rangle\otimes (\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}|0\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}|1\rangle)
$$
if you work it through, so qubit $B$ is in the state
$$
\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}|0\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}|1\rangle
$$
as claimed. (If you check the normalisation carefully, you find that you get this measurement result with probability 1/2.)

Thanks for the answer; 2 follow up questions:
Am I correct in saying that in $(|+\rangle \langle +| \otimes I)$, the $I$ represents $B$ being left alone while the $|+\rangle \langle +|$ is the operator representing measurement of $A$ in $| + \rangle$? So if we were measuring $B$ instead, then we'd have $(I \otimes |+\rangle \langle +|)$?
Also I noted when expanding out the first expression that the result is $| + \rangle \otimes (\frac{2}{\sqrt 10} |0 \rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt 10} |1 \rangle)$. Does this extra $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ factor represent the $1/2$ probability that you mentioned?

(continued) Following taketoshi's response below, I note that $|\langle + | \psi \rangle_{AB}|^2$ equals $4/10 + 1/10 = 1/2$ — so in the state $| \psi \rangle_{AB}$, probability of $A = | + \rangle$ or $| - \rangle$ is $1/2$, therefore the probability that $B = \frac{2}{\sqrt 5} |0 \rangle +   \frac{1}{\sqrt 5} |1 \rangle$ is the same as the probability that $B =  \frac{2}{\sqrt 5} |0 \rangle -   \frac{1}{\sqrt 5} |1 \rangle$, which is also $1/2$; I assume this is where the normalisation relates to the probability of each result

Yes to both of your questions :)

$|\psi\rangle_{AB} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}|0\rangle_A \otimes |0\rangle_B + \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}|1\rangle_A \otimes |1\rangle_B$
first, we know :
$|+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)$
$|-\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle)$
now, if we express $|0\rangle/|1\rangle$ basis in terms of $|+\rangle/|-\rangle$ basis,
$|0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+\rangle + |-\rangle)$
$|1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+\rangle - |-\rangle)$
next, substitute these $|0\rangle, |1\rangle$ into $|0\rangle_A$,  $|1\rangle_A$ in $|\psi\rangle_{AB}$, then we get :
$|\psi\rangle_{AB} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+\rangle + |-\rangle) \otimes |0\rangle_B + \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+\rangle - |-\rangle) \otimes |1\rangle_B$
$=  |+\rangle \otimes \left( \frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}|0\rangle_B + \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}|1\rangle_B \right) + |-\rangle \otimes \left( \frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}|0\rangle_B - \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}|1\rangle_B \right)$
if we measure qubit A as $|+\rangle$, then qubit B becomes :
$\frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}|0\rangle_B + \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}|1\rangle_B$
normalizing the state gives :
$\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}|0\rangle_B + \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}|1\rangle_B$
and that is what your notes mentioned.

The reduced state for $B$ is not independent of the measurement basis on $A$. given a measurement in the computational basis on $A$, the reduced state for $B$ will either be $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$. Given a measurement in the $\{|+\rangle, |-\rangle \}$basis on $A$, as pointed out by DaftWullie, the state will either be $$\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}|0\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}|1\rangle$$ or $$\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}|0\rangle-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}|1\rangle$$
The density matrix elements for these 4 post measured states for $B$ are all different.
Unless $B$ was product with $A$ in the first place, then depending on the measurement basis on $A$, the reduced state of $B$, and as such the elements of it's density matrix, should change.
